# AngularJS call function of object in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following controller:

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  $scope.tests = [{
      name: 'Name 1',
      description: 'Some Description',
      actionHandler: function() {
        alert('Action Handler called');
      }
    },
    ...
  ];
});
```

In my [html](/questions/tagged/html)file I do an **`ng-repeat`** like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="test in tests">
  <p>{{test.name}}</p>
  <p>{{test.description}}</p>
  <a ng-click="{{test.actionHandler}}">Click me</a>
</div>
```

It is not really working. I also tried.

```
<a ng-click="test.actionHandler">Click me</a>
```

And

```
 <a ng-click="test.actionHandler()">Click me</a>
```

But none seem to work. Any idea how I can call a function of an object inside **`ng-repeat`**?

Thanks, xCoder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your third stab is the correct form `test.actionHandler()`. Perhaps you could try including $window along side $scope in your controller `'TestContorller', function($scope, $window)` and change the alert call to `$window.alert('action handler called')` ...

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `{{}}` and invoke the function within `ng-click`

```
<a ng-click="test.actionHandler()">Click me</a>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/8J8d5E9yjory84VGtY0Y)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I will do it like this

For html:

```
<div ng-repeat="test in tests">
   <p ng-bind="test.name"></p>
   <p ng-bind="test.description"></p>
   <a ng-click="test.actionHandler($index)">Click me</a>
</div>
```

For Controller

```
app.controller('TestController',function($scope) {
   $scope.tests = [
      {
         name: 'Name 1',
         description: 'Some Description',
      },
   ];

   scope.actionHandler = function(index) 
   {
      alert('Action Handler called for'+$scope.tests[index]['name']);
   }

});
```

Use ng-bind instead of the curly braces. That is my tip to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new event handler in the controller:

```
app.controller('TestController',function($scope) {

   $scope.handleClick = function(){
       alert('Action Handler called');   
   }

});
```

And then your link would be:

```
<a ng-click="handleClick()">Click me</a>
```

If you need a handler for a specific test then just pass an id (for example) to the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Only remove the curly braces and add parentheses `()`.

```
ng-click="test.actionHandler()"
```

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  angular.module("myApp", []).controller("Controller", ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
      $scope.tests = [{
        name: "Name 1",
        description: "Some Description...",
        actionHandler: function() {
          alert("Action Handler called");
          console.log(this);
        }
      }, {
        name: "Name 2",
        description: "Some Description 2...",
        actionHandler: function() {
          alert("Action Handler called");
          console.log(this);
        }
      }];
    }
  ]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
  <div data-ng-controller="Controller">
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="test in tests">{{test.name}}
        <br />
        <button data-ng-click="test.actionHandler()" type="button">Test</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/n7r0zyer/)</kbd>